# How can I set HikariCP maxlifetime under 30s?

Tags: hikaricp

I know hikaricp's minimum `maxlifetime` is 30s, but is there any way to set it to something less than 30s?

When I try to set `maxLifetime = 5000,` it doesn't work:

> maxLifetime is less than 30000ms, using default 1800000ms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want a pool at all with a lifetime so short. What is the use case? You can set *idleTimeout* as low as 10s. If *minimumIdle* is less than *maximumPoolSize*, then *idleTimeout* will be honored.